# Converting ångström spectral dimension to galaxy speed (km/s)

Tags: spectroscopy, spectra, units

I have a spectral cube (in FITS format) whose spectral dimension is in ångströms. The sampling along the spectral dimension is 0.28A (CDELT=0.28). The observation in the cube is Ha emission of a galaxy at redshift 0.1.

How can I convert the sampling to km/s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want bins that have an equal step in km/s then you will have to rebin in steps of equal log wavelength. On this scale the rest wavelength of H alpha is at zero km/s and then each bin will represent a increment in velocity with respect to that.

See [How do I apply a velocity shift to a wavelength array with uniform logarithmic spacing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/how-do-i-apply-a-velocity-shift-to-a-wavelength-array-with-uniform-logarithmic-s?rq=1)