# Logarithmic rebinning and continuum removal of stellar spectra

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, data-analysis, spectra, python

I am trying to learn how to derive the line of sight velocity distributions from galaxy spectrum to extract kinematical parameters like rotational velocity and velocity dispersion. Therefore I need to do some prepare my spectra. For this example I took a stellar spectra from the Miles-catalogue http://miles.iac.es/pages/stellar-libraries/the-catalogue.php. I tried to rebin the spectra onto a logarithmic wavelength scale and then I tried to remove the continuum as described by Bender et. al 1994, [Line-of-sight velocity distributions of elliptical galaxies](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994MNRAS.269..785B/abstract) (also available [here](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/269/3/785/1002169) and in [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228075911_Line_of_sight_velocity_distributions_of_elliptical_galaxies)).

Here is the relevant part of the paper:

> 3.1 Reduction and derivation of line-of-sight velocity
> distributions
>
> The CCD spectra were de-biased, dark-subtracted and flatfielded in the usual way. Hot pixels and cosmic ray events
> were removed with a $\kappa$—$\sigma$ clipping procedure. Then, the spectra were rebinned to a logarithmic wavelength scale and the
> mean sky spectrum during each exposure was derived by averaging several lines from the edges of the CCD spectra. After
> subtraction of the sky spectra, spectra of the same galaxy
> taken at identical slit positions were centred and added. Then,
> the spectra were rebinned along the slit in order to guarantee
> a signal-to-noise ratio that allowed the derivation of kinematic
> parameters. As the final step of the pre-processing, the galaxy
> continuum was removed in two steps. First, a fourth- to sixthorder polynomial was fitted to each line-by-line spectrum.
> Then, the rms variation $\sigma_s$ of the spectrum around the fitted
> polynomial was calculated and the fit was repeated including
> only those pixels of which the value fell in a range between 0$\sigma_s$
> and 2$\sigma_s$ around the first fit. Finally, the spectrum was divided
> by this second fit polynomial. This procedure avoids the fact
> that the stronger absorption lines disturb the fit and leads to
> a satisfactory approximation of the galaxy ‘continuum’. This
> method of continuum removal was found to be superior to the
> usually applied procedures which include filtering in Fourier
> space. The reason is that filtering in Fourier space may change
> the profiles of the absorption lines in such a way that the
> derived $H_4$ values (see below) may be systematically offset
> with respect to the true values. The appropriate order of the...

(original [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaSae.jpg))

I am not certain if I performed this correctly. Here is my code:

```
# read in 1D spectral data, which is conventionally stored in FITS format
# read in stellar template spectra from miles library http://miles.iac.es/
# by Vazdekis (2010, MNRAS, 404, 1639)
miles_dir = r"C:\Users\reich\OneDrive\Dokumente\Uni\Bachelorarbeit\Python\ppxf\MILES_library_v9.1_FITS"
file = miles_dir + '/s0427.fits'    # s0427 K2III-star
# header data unit (HDUs) list are the highest level component of the FITS file structure
# hdu.info() summarizes content of opened fits file
hdu = fits.open(file)
# HDU objects consist of a header and a data unit/attributes
# to read the entire header one can use print(repr(hdr))
hdr = hdu[0].header
data = hdu[0].data
# extract numpy arrays for flux and wavelength from data
flux_raw = data[0]
w = WCS(hdr, naxis=1, relax=False, fix=False)
lam = w.wcs_pix2world(np.arange(len(flux_raw)), 0)[0]
# logarithmic wavelength scale to obtain constant velocity scale
# for N pixels in wavelength-array, need to rebin spectra
# to atleast N pixels in log-wavelength
log_lam_raw = np.log(lam)
# logarithmic rebinning
log_lam = np.linspace(min(log_lam_raw), max(log_lam_raw), num=len(lam))

# remove continuum of spectra
def fit_polynom(log_lam, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5):
    """fit func = 2 nd order polynom"""
    return a0+a1*log_lam+a2*(log_lam)**2+a3*(log_lam)**3+a4*(log_lam)**4+a5*(log_lam)**5
# intitialize fit paramters
init_fit_param = [0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0]
# fit data using scipy.curve_fit()
fit_params, fit_covariances = curve_fit(fit_polynom, log_lam, flux_raw, p0=init_fit_param)
# calculate root mean square deviation
rms_array = np.sqrt((flux_raw - fit_polynom(log_lam, *fit_params))**2)
# only use flux values for 2nd fit which have a rms value < 2
fit_params2, fit_covariances2 = curve_fit(fit_polynom, log_lam[np.argwhere(rms_array<=2)][:,0], flux_raw[np.argwhere(rms_array <= 2)][:,0], p0=init_fit_param)
# remove continuum by dividing flux by fit polynomial
flux = (flux_raw / (fit_polynom(log_lam, *fit_params2))) -1
```

I chose a fipolynom of order 5 this can obviously be varied, but shouldnt be the main concern. This is a plot of the flux over wavelength and flux over logarithmic rebinned wavelength with the fitpolynom.[image]

And here is a plot with the "removed" continuum, which does not seem quite right.
[image]

So can someone please tell me if a) I did the logarithmic rebinning correct and b) if my approach to the continuum removal makes sense or should be varied. I want to further work with the continuum removed spectra and extract line of sight velocity distributions (for galaxies ), but need to be sure that I understand the preprep correctly. Thank you very much

Comment: Why is you final spectrum $\sim 0$? The paper you refers to divides by the continuum fit, which should leave the spectrum close to 1.  Obviously if you divide (or subtract)  a small number by a (uncertain) small number at the blue wavelength edge then you could get unpredictable behaviour. The x-axis values don't make any sense. Logarithmic rebinning doesn't change the x-axis values/range it just adaptively changes the size of the bins so that each one is an equal step in $\log \lambda$.

Comment: I found a copy of the paper with selectable text and replaced your screenshot. Some folks use screen readers that convert text to audio and *images of text* don't process usually, so that is generally discouraged in Stack Exchange.

Comment: I was biased by a plot in the paper I referred to because there the flux was arround 0, that is why I subtracted 1 from the whole flux array for this plot which I just fixed. So should I only work further without the blue wave length end in this case to avoid this behaviour ? For the logarithmic rebinning I think I am lacking some understanding of the phrases used, and I am sorry if this should be obvious. What exactly is meant by bin, and size of the bin in this context ? I got an array for the flux and one for the wavelength, I thought I had to reconstruct the wavelength array ?

Comment: My guess it that a bin in this context means a particular range of wavelengths?

Comment: Your input data (the MILES template spectrum) is binned by linear wavelength: each element of the wavelength vector specifies a "bin"; for example, if lam[i] = 4800 (Angstroms), then it defines a bin containing photons with wavelengths ranging from 4800 - deltaLam/2 to 4800 + deltaLam/2, where deltaLam is the wavelength spacing (the size of the bins).

Comment: "Logarithmically rebinning" means converting your spectrum so the wavelength vector defines bins with a constant size in log(wavelength) rather than a constant size in linear wavelength, which is what you're starting with. Your log_lam is what you want, but you also need to actually rebin the *flux* (e.g., flux_raw) so that it agrees with the rebinned log wavelength bins.

Comment: You might look at the "log_rebin" function in Michele Cappellari's pPXF package (in the ppxf_util.py module).

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful explanation, I have already started to work a bit with the ppxf package to test my work. Is there a command in python where I can see the exact definition of the log_rebin() function in the ppxf_util module ?

Comment: @trynerror It's defined in the ppxf_util.py module, which is pure Python; you can open the Python file in a text editor. (You may have to figure out where your system installs external Python packages in order to locate the ppxf package.)

Comment: Related https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14518/why-do-linear-velocity-redshifts-correspond-to-linear-pixel-shifts-when-the-spec